# Raphael SVG Sample - Where are the colors coming from?

Tags: svg, raphael, vector-graphics

**Page my question is referring to: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html**

Can some kind individual please tell me where the color codes for each of these Australian states are coming from within the code?

This function applies colors onmouseover, but I can't see where it's getting the colors from.

```
st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc"}, 500);
```

Where is 'st.color' getting the fill colors from?

**Page my question is referring to: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They come from this line:

```
aus[state].color = Raphael.getColor();
```

`aus[state]` is then passed to the subsequent immediately-invoked function expression as `st`:

```
                (function (st, state) {
                    ...
                })(aus[state], state);
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Where is Raphael.getColor(); getting the color codes from though? On hover the states turn different colors, where are these different colors stored in the code? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. So it appears that Raphael.getColor(); is essentially a "random" color.